# 8021 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.wrapException(Client.java:1095)

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

Hi I am trying to configure Hadoop 1.0. in pseudodistributed mode by following this blog.

http://hadoop-tutorial.blogspot.de/2010/11/running-hadoop-in-pseudo-distributed.html?showComment=1337083501000#c615470573579885293.

But when I run the pi example given in the hadoop distribution, I get the error mentioned in title. Can someone please help me and guide me how can I fix this problem. Also its a request that please suggest solution as well if possible along with pinpinting the problem.

here is what i get by running jps

```
8322 Jps
7611 SecondaryNameNode
7474 DataNode
7341 NameNode
```

Here is complete error message.

```
Number of Maps  = 10
Samples per Map = 100
Wrote input for Map #0
Wrote input for Map #1
Wrote input for Map #2
Wrote input for Map #3
Wrote input for Map #4
Wrote input for Map #5
Wrote input for Map #6
Wrote input for Map #7
Wrote input for Map #8
Wrote input for Map #9
Starting Job
12/05/16 13:11:56 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8021. Already tried 0 time(s).
12/05/16 13:11:57 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8021. Already tried 1 time(s).
12/05/16 13:11:58 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8021. Already tried 2 time(s).
12/05/16 13:11:59 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8021. Already tried 3 time(s).
12/05/16 13:12:00 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8021. Already tried 4 time(s).
12/05/16 13:12:01 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8021. Already tried 5 time(s).
12/05/16 13:12:02 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8021. Already tried 6 time(s).
12/05/16 13:12:03 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8021. Already tried 7 time(s).
12/05/16 13:12:04 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8021. Already tried 8 time(s).
12/05/16 13:12:05 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8021. Already tried 9 time(s).
java.net.ConnectException: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:8021 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.wrapException(Client.java:1095)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1071)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:225)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.$Proxy2.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:396)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:379)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.createRPCProxy(JobClient.java:480)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.init(JobClient.java:474)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.<init>(JobClient.java:457)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1260)
        at org.apache.hadoop.examples.PiEstimator.estimate(PiEstimator.java:297)
        at org.apache.hadoop.examples.PiEstimator.run(PiEstimator.java:342)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
        at org.apache.hadoop.examples.PiEstimator.main(PiEstimator.java:351)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:68)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:139)
        at org.apache.hadoop.examples.ExampleDriver.main(ExampleDriver.java:64)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:701)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:656)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:434)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:560)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2000(Client.java:184)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1202)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1046)
        ... 24 more
```

Comment: can you run a `netstat -atn | grep LISTEN` and confirm that port 8021 is listening?

Comment: no it does not:( how can i fix it?

Comment: I see your running this via the hadoop mailing lists too (which there is nothing wrong with) - have you tried running the `start-mapred.sh` script (see my answer)?

Comment: assuming you are doing this on a Mac OSX system, make sure System Preferences -> Sharing > Remote Login is enabled

Answer (score 3):

Your `jps` output shows that you do not have a JobTracker nor TaskTracker running - hence the connection issue when trying to communicate with the jobtracker.

Check the logs for the jobtracker (`$HADOOP_HOME/logs/*.jobtracker*.log`) to see if there is an error message describing why it hasn't started (how did you start the cluster - `start-all.sh` or `start-dfs.sh`, maybe try running `start-mapred.sh` to see if that starts up your map reduce services)?

Comment: I tried it too but cant get jobtracker or tasktracker in jps output

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is some connection related issue. 
Is your jobtracker and trasktracker running correctly ?

See this [link](https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/group/cdh-user/browse_thread/thread/1fac007dd78b209a)

**Edit:**

Read the Appendix A [here](http://lib.dsu.dp.ua/books/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%98%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85/NoSQL%20books/Hadoop/Hadoop%20The%20Definitive%20Guide%202nd%20Edition%20%28Oreilly%29%20%5B2010%5D.pdf) in Definitive Guide. Its has entire steps for setting up a hadoop server in all 3 modes. I think that your configurations might be creating problems so use those that are prescribed in the book. Also check if password-less SSH is working fine on yr setup.

Comment: I also believe that jobtracker and tasktracker are not initialized as JPS output suggested. can you please guide me that what should I do to make them running.

Comment: Thanks TejasP. Infact I have hadoop 0.20 setup on my system and is running fine so it means that passwordless SSH is working fine. please correct me if I am wrong(I am not good at all in all this commandline linux things)

Comment: is it that u are using the same configuration for both hadoop setups at the same time ? that might also cause problems.

Comment: no i am running one at a time. Also i used different ports for both of them

Comment: try with the steps in Definitive guide and in case u face problem, post the exception from Jobtracker and Tasktracker logs

Comment: here are the links for jobtracker.out and jobtracker.log file http://pastebin.com/bvWZRt0A      http://pastebin.com/4YCZhQGh

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11335/discussion-between-tejasp-and-waqas)

Comment: see the jobtracker outfile. something terrible happnd to JVM and it crashed. An error report file with more information is saved as: /data/hadoop/hadoop-1.0.0/hs_err_pid31211.log

Answer (score 0):

i met same issue, it is becasue hadoop 1.0.x has a difference need config two variables in hadoop_env.sh:

export HADOOP_HEAPSIZE=2000

## Extra Java runtime options.  Empty by default.

## export HADOOP_OPTS=-server

export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.security.krb5.realm=OX.AC.UK -Djava.security.krb5.kdc=kdc0.ox.ac.uk:kdc1.ox.ac.uk"

when you add these two variables, you will not see any error or warning during starting daemons, so that you can resolve your issue. good luck!

wish my answer can help other guys:)

Answer (score 0):

From the jps output looks like the `TaskTracker` and `JobTracker` are not running. Try running:

```
start-mapred.sh
```

This would start the `TaskTracker` and `JobTracker` and try rerunning job.